# how to add all changes one by one with confirmation on git

Tags: git, git-add

team,
is there a way I can add all my changes one by one with confirmation?

example: if I changed 10 files, then I should be prompted 10 times to add change or no. I don't want to do "git add -A" or add every change manually. is there an automatic way which prompts y/n before adding on git?

Answer (score 6):

For changes in files already in the repo (as opposed to adding new files to repo) you may want to use `git add --patch` (`git add -p`). From [doco](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work tree and add them to the index. This gives the user a chance to review the difference before adding modified contents to the index.
>       This effectively runs add --interactive, but bypasses the initial command menu and directly jumps to the patch subcommand. See “Interactive mode” for details.

Let's consider two files were changed:

```
tymtam@xxx:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   1.txt
        modified:   2.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Let's add them one by one:

```
tymtam@xxx:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git add --patch
diff --git a/1.txt b/1.txt
index e69de29..9d60796 100644
--- a/1.txt
+++ b/1.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+11
\ No newline at end of file
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? y

diff --git a/2.txt b/2.txt
index e1f9ded..8fdd954 100644
--- a/2.txt
+++ b/2.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-x echo y
+22
\ No newline at end of file
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? y
```

Done:

```
tymtam@xxx:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   1.txt
        modified:   2.txt

tymtam@xxx:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$
```

---

Let me reiterate that this will not interact with new files.

For example:

```
tymek@LAPTOP-B0OQU3LB:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   1.txt
        modified:   2.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        3.txt
```

Let's try `add --patch`

```
tymek@LAPTOP-B0OQU3LB:/mnt/c/git/sandbox$ git add --patch
No changes.
```

For interactive adding of unstaged files please refer to `git add --interactive`. The doco can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_interactive_mode).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at interactive staging

`git add -i`

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging